# Mitigation techniques for slow thread processing

Tags: java, multithreading

Given a synchronous program (Minecraft) that needs to process x lighting updates when the world is generating. A technique to increasing performance, is to patch Minecraft to instead queue the lighting updates, then process them asynchronously, removing any duplicate scheduled lighting updates from the queue.

This is to provide some duplication removal, as well as spreading out the load of world generation over the next few tick cycles.

This queue is currently unbounded, and before the duplicate location check, would be the source of poor performance or memory leaks as the queue grew to ridiculous sizes.

What can you do to solve the memory leak in the case that the queue is growing faster then it's processing? Are there techniques to force a thread to get more time, or block until the queue is under a certain length? We can't provide back pressure, as that would cause lost lighting updates that wouldn't necessarily be rescheduled. Also potentially having a max queued time before promising processing could be ideal.

I would have provided code, / asked in more abstract terms, But I'm not sure of the specifics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot slow down a thread as such, other than by putting sleep statements into it. You can play with thread priorities, but that simply changes the order in which threads are scheduled. This may have the effect of slowing down a thread, but only if there are higher priority threads taking all the run time.

What you need is some sort of work quantity regulator, not a work rate regulator. That is, attempt to do only as much work as can be performed by the underlying machine. You may want to look at ZeroMQ: this would be a big architectural change (asynchronous for a start!), but stick with me for a moment.

Programming with ZeroMQ is Actor model; threads communicate down sockets, which act like message queues. The beauty is that there's way more to these sockets than simply a point-to-point link; there's patterns too. For example, you might have 8 threads doing lighting. You would send lighting requests to those through a single PUSH/PULL socket; the one that is available will pick up that message and process it. You would also configure that socket so that if the high water mark is reached (lighting threads aren't keeping up) new lighting request messages supplant old ones in the queue (the lighting threads process only as many as they can actually cope with, biased towards the newest ones).

And the sockets can go over network connections too. You'd be able to distribute it over several computers with hardly any code changes.

There are problems with this suggestion of mine: you'd be serialising and deserialising objects an awful lot. You'd be tearing up the existing architecture. But you would be leveraging a comms framework that distributes, scales, and already does load balancing and queue management in a useful way. It would be fun to try!

**EDIT in response to comment**

One thing I can think of is to add a submission time-of-day field to a lighting request, and have the lighting thread(s) calculate the time between initial submission of each request and when they complete the processing. This execution time measurement could be used to update an average time-to-completion value across all lighting threads (put it in some shared memory guarded by a mutex, or something like that).

The thing submitting the lighting requests could then refer to this average, and if it's increasing, it should ease up on the rate. Similarly if the average processing time is decreasing, it could up the rate. If the computer itself started getting busy doing something else in the background, this would then adapt to that shortage of execution time.

Effectively this is building profiling of the lighting processing into the application, feeding that back to the submitter, and learning during execution just how many lighting requests per second can be submitted without falling too far behind.

This would have the side effect of ensuring that the queue itself doesn't get too full and grow indefinitely. It's not bounding the queue to any particular length, but it is limiting how much time there is between the front and back of the queue. So on a faster machine, the queue will on average be longer, and shorter on a slower machine.

*Thermal Management in CPUs*

Of course, the definition of a "fast" and "slow" computer is a bit complicated these days. A modern Intel / AMD CPU (and lots of ARMs too) will ramp up its clock rate if it determines that there's a lot of runtime required. So the lighting request rate that can be sustained is going to increase as the CPU works out that Turbo mode is required, ramps up the clock rate, things run faster. So by adapting to the rate that can be sustained whilst meeting a time target (i.e. keeping the average completion time reasonable), your code will make use of the increased speed of the CPU as it gets used to the workload you're asking it to do.

You will need to be a bit careful though; changing clock speed is not instantaneous - I've seen 300ms delays during which literally nothing happens anywhere in entire machine - which when they happen will look like everything has suddenly taken 300ms longer. That's why the "average" completion time is required - it'll smooth out pertebation in the measurement.

Getting the length of the average right will matter too, otherwise you'll get into a condition where your code's demands on the CPU and the CPU's clock rate will oscilate:

- Your code ups the workload,
- the CPU responds by upping the clock rate, this takes 300ms to accomplish,
- your code detects an unexpected jump in latency and reduces the workload,
- the CPU notices the drop in demand and reduces the clock rate,
- your code over compensates, and cuts the workload even more
- the latency reduces again,
- start again...

Also you will want to be ramping up the workload even if the average completion time has reached stability. If could be that doing so pushes the CPU to up its clock rate, and more lighting requests can be done without impacting on the completion time.

Basically you want to be increasing the workload, and only reducing it if the latency actually increases, but doing so over a timescale slower than the CPU's own thermal management / clock management cycles.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I appreciate the response for learning purposes, but unfortunately introducing new frameworks isn't really a solution as we are patching and reverse engineering the base Minecraft game.

Do you have further information about work quantity regulator vs work rate regulator that would require minimal intervention to standard Java8 thread handling, or maybe some libraries that would have collections / threads / executors suitable?

Comment: @RyanTheLeach No worries. I've added an idea along the lines of self-profiling to the end of the answer, which should fit in with standard Java threading / mutexes / shared memory reasonably well. Good luck!

Comment: **A lovely read, @bazza** ( as always ). Besides the CPU-hardwired thermal management, one ought recently also become careful about mainboard-implemented "external" power-throtling influences, observed to make issues in extreme HPC infrastructures ( having adverse effects on right-tuning the critical section, where power is needed on max, not on "green"-eco-terrorist-motivated down-scaling ... funny how hard it was for LLNL HPC-experts to find a way to cope with this new-dimension of exo-system performance-killer "ghost" ).

Comment: @user3666197, why, thank you :-) It's certainly the case that the HPC guys, anyone doing real-ish time work (e.g myself), etc. are more willing to burn up a few Coulombs 24/7. Did the LLNL guys run into problems with CPU power management? Normally a HPC workload is "as quick as you can", so I'd expect the CPU clock to ramp up and stay there (usually no work rate throttling in the software). To get "firm" real time code working on Intel I needed specialised BIOS settings, basically keeping the CPU on full power 24/7. Worked quite well, not cheap...

Comment: Sure, LLNL guys are pretty well aware of what HPC needs and can squeeze all the powers till the last drop. Their new and interesting experience came from a need to deliver max power to CPU not to become down-clocked and how to avoid any and all "out-of-band" automation, thermal-stepping etc, tec, to prevent any sort of the CPU-power throttling on the new generation CPU/MoBo-hardware ( some being independent of any code-driven controls -- bypassing BIOS services, having separate mBUS etc ). BTW, **+ you might like a new, live `occam-pi`** online IDE, found at **https://tio.run/#occam-pi** :o)

Answer (score 1):

> What can you do to solve the memory leak in the case that the queue is growing faster then it's processing?

In that case, increasing memory footprints are probably your smallest problem.

> Are there techniques to force a thread to get more time, or block until the queue is under a certain length?

Java threads can be prioritized, but it very much depends on the underlying operating system if leads to observable effects.

It is hard to help beyond the above - you see, as this depends very much on the details of the architecture/implementation. I would be looking into questions such as:

- are there enough threads?
- is the underlying hardware powerful enough for the expected traffic?

You see - it seems that you can't influence the number of events flowing *into* your system. So you simply have to design a solution that *works* for that flow. This is a specific problem that requires that you sit down and *profile* your threads for example: to understand where and how they spend their time. And the conclusion might be for example that the machine doing these computations hasn't enough horse power. But is something that *you* have to do.

Comment: If the async load grows too much, we can potentially slow down the game processing / tick speed so the memory limit isn't reached. We can't directly control the amount of lighting updates needing to be generated, but we could potentially slow the 'main' thread down in order to process the queue down to a manageable amount again aka, do some *synchronous* lighting updates. I was hoping to see a link to a resource that describes some patterns / queues / architecture designs that would potentially support this.